# what is the difference between filters and hooks & how can i use them in child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

What is the difference between filter and hooks in wordpress.

How can i use the following filter in child theme ?

```
<?php
foreach ( $results as $result ) {
// external plugins can modify or disable field
$result = apply_filters( 'cp_package_field', $result, 'ad' );
if ( ! $result )
continue;
?>
```

how can i use the following hook in child theme ?

```
/**
* called in cp_add_new_listing() to hook into inserting new ad process
*
* @since 3.2.1
* @param int $post_id
*
*/
function cp_action_add_new_listing( $post_id ) {
do_action( 'cp_action_add_new_listing', $post_id );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, here is a link to an explanation I found a while back that was pretty comprehensive and it helped me to understand the difference.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/difference-between-filter-and-action-hooks

Answer (score 0):

To use the hook in your child theme, you'd probably need to have the following piece of code in your child theme's `functions.php` file:

```
/**
 * Our callback function to the hook
 * @param  int $post_id id of the post
 * @return void
 */
function my_child_theme_new_listing_cb( $post_id ) {
    if($post_id == 10) { //Or whatever you want
        echo 'Hello World';
    }
    //We do not have the responsibility to return something as it is a hook
}

add_action( 'cp_action_add_new_listing', 'my_child_theme_new_listing_cb', 10, 1 );
```

Hope it helps.